# nginx rewrite to redirect domain to domain2

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'd like to redirect `www.mydomain.com` to `www.mydomain2.com/try.html`. These domains are on two different servers.

This is what I've tried but it does not work:

```
if ($http_referer ~* (www.mydomain.com) ) {
return 301 http://www.mydomain2.com/try.html;
}
```

OR

```
if ($http_referer ~* (www.mydomain.com) ) {
rewrite ^ http://mydomain2.com/try.html permanent;
}
```

These two ways are not working, when I go to `mydomain.com` I stay on `mydomain.com` but... without the CSS... And I am not redirected to `mydomain2.com/try.html`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add new `server` section to your nginx config file

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    rewrite         ^ http://www.mydomain2.com/try.html permanent;
}
```

and all visitors of mydomain.com will be redirected to second site immediately.